# Apache Storm-Starter: Intellij IDEA: Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalCluster'; Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDPRC'

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-storm

I intend to try out storm-starter.

I followed instructions under header "Importing storm-starter as a project in IDEA" at https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter .*****

[image]

***** With 3 differences (that I don't think resulted in the errors mentioned later in this post):

1) I imported all the modules instead of just storm-starter.  That is, I imported at a higher level directory (*somePath/incubator-storm/* instead of *somePath/incubator-storm/examples/storm-starter*).

2) I am using Oracle JDK 7. Specifically, Java 1.7.0_60.  Instructions recommend JDK 6.

3) During the import, I requested IDEA to have Maven sources and dependencies downloaded automatically.

---

Errors were encountered in Intellij IDEA:

Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalCluster'

Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDPRC'

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue and I finally resolved by realizing that you need to do

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

at the top storm directory to build your storm first.

Answer (score 0):

If this also does not work and you are using IntelliJ ... Just install Clojure plugin for IntelliJ. The reason for the error is that your IDE is unable to parse the Clojure code corresponding to Localcluster class in Storm.